# What is the best way to learn a drum part of a song

Tags: sheet-music, drums, self-learning

So i have this song that i have to learn which is having some fast and complicated drum fills and i do not have the sheet for it.

I am trying to play along but also the production is not one of the best and i cannot hear clearly the drums while playing.

What is the best way to at least get a basic start?

Or is there someone that can tell me what patterns are used in the song maybe?
The song is from the band Ancst and it's called Entropie.

Any advice or ideas are welcome.

Comment: Sometimes live versions bring out some things that you couldn't hear on album and vice versa. Along with a good pair of earphones / speakers. Don't forget videos to see some being played.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the means and the skill, you could drag and drop the song into a DAW and play around with the track to try and bring out some of the drums in the song. Also, you can slow it down that way as well, which I find the best way of learning songs.

Slow it down as much as you can bear, listen to every little detail and then learn it section by section, speeding up as you get the hang of it. However this will be different for everyone, this is just how I learn songs on drums and guitar.

Answer (score 0):

In general I've found that drum covers on Youtube are great for learning a drum part visually..

I took a look for Ancst/Entropie and couldn't find any drum covers for it, alas, so that won't help you now, but for the future...

Comment: hey thanks for your answer. So in the end i just took audacity (since i use linux) and cut the parts of the song and then slow them down up to 60% so i can hear all the beats and small details.

Answer (score 0):

Songsterr or TabPro....you can do all sort of things such as slow the tempo down replay the part you choose over and over until you get it...see the notes as the song plays so you learn to read music as well if you dont know already
 and seeing the notes can help alot of times on difficult parts that hearing just doesnt cut it.  check it out you wont regret it.  oh and you can remove all the other instruments in the song one at a time....lower their volume and increase the one of your choice which would be drums in our case...